# 2 forms that are mistakenly being submitted only to one

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-modal

While trying to add an additional form to the site somehow the confirmation of the first form confirms the second form and the first form will not submit at all.

First form

```
<aside class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 sidebar">
                    <form class="appointment-form dark" method="post" action="confirmation/index.php">
                        <h1>Request an Appointment</h1>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="first_name">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="first_name" name="first_name">
                        </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="current_url" value="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group no-label">
                            <button class="btn" data-submitting="Requesting..." data-submitted="Requested <i class='fa fa-check'></i>">Request Now</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="fancybox form-confirmation">
                        <div class="inside">
                            <h1>Thank you for requesting an appointment <span class="data-name"></span>! We'll get back to you shortly.</h1>
                            <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Second form

```
                              <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                              <h4 class="modal-title">Insurance Check</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
<form class="contact">
                                  <style type="text/css">
                                  .form-group-ic{margin-bottom:8px;}
                                  span.alert{font-size:10px; padding:10px 0px;}
                                  </style>
                                  <div class="form-group-ic" style="width:44%;float:left;">
                                      <label for="first_name_ic">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="first_name_ic" name="first_name_ic">
                                  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="current_url" value="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"/>
                                  <div class="form-group-ic no-label">
                                      <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn" style="background:#0e704b;" value="Request Now" />
                                  </div>
                              </form>
```

Comment: You need to provide enough information to reproduce the problem. Presumably the fault is in some JavaScript that you haven't shared with us.  A *reduced* test case that demonstrates the problem without extraneous markup and with a minimum number of inputs would be best. http://sscce.org/

Comment: You have a couple of fairly obvious errors. Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="current_url" value="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"/>` — **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: I ran the validator and updated the example. Can you take a second look?

Comment: You can't have a `<style>` inside a `<form>` so it doesn't look like you paid that much attention to the validator, more to the point, there still isn't enough information here to reproduce the problem. As I said in my first comment, I can't see how you get the problem you describe without the involvement of JavaScript and you haven't included any.